# debugger group base members as tree VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, inheritance, visual-studio-debugging

Is it still possible to configure the Visual Studio 2015 debugger to display objects including a "base" entry, that shows inherited members in layers?

<s>Or did ReSharper do this to me?</s>
No, it did not.

this is how i want it to look again:

[image: Visual Studio 2013 Debugger]

This is how it looks like:

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Debugger]

Edit: My VS setup is:

> ```
> Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
> Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
> Microsoft .NET Framework
> Version 4.6.00081
>
> Installierte Version: Enterprise
>
> Architecture and Modeling Tools   00322-80000-00000-AA968
> Microsoft Architecture and Modeling Tools
>
> UML® und Unified Modeling Language™ sind Marken oder eingetragene Marken der Object Management Group, Inc. in den Vereinigten Staaten
> und anderen Ländern.
>
> LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2015   00322-80000-00000-AA968
> Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2015
>
> Visual Basic 2015   00322-80000-00000-AA968
> Microsoft Visual Basic 2015
>
> Visual C# 2015   00322-80000-00000-AA968
> Microsoft Visual C# 2015
>
> Visual C++ 2015   00322-80000-00000-AA968
> Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
>
> Allgemeine Azure-Tools   1.5
> Bietet allgemeine Dienste für die Verwendung durch Azure Mobile Services und Microsoft Azure-Tools.
>
> AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio   2.5.12582.28
> AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio 2.5.12582.28 
>  * Ankh.Package 2.5.12582.28
>  * Subversion 1.8.11 via SharpSvn 1.8011.3473.77
>
> SharpSvn is linked to: Apr 1.5.1, Apr-util 1.5.4, Cyrus Sasl 2.1.25, eXpat 2.1.0, OpenSSL 1.0.1l 15 Jan 2015, serf 1.3.8, SQLite 3.7.17, Subversion 1.8.11-SharpSvn-1.8.11, ZLib 1.2.8
> SharpSvn is optionally linked to: Berkeley DB 4.4.20, SharpPlink 1.8011.3473.77
>
> ASP.NET- und Webtools   14.0.20626.0
> ASP.NET- und Webtools
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.30624.0
> For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/
>
> JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2015.1.3   Build 102.0.20150724.141603
> JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper Ultimate, visit
> http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper. Copyright © 2015 JetBrains, Inc.
>
> Komponententest generieren   1.0
> Generiert Komponententestcode für Methoden in zu testenden Klassen.
>
> Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
> Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools
>
> Microsoft Code Digger   0.9
> Microsoft Code Digger
>
> Microsoft.Pex.VisualStudio   1.0
> Pex
>
> NuGet-Paket-Manager   3.2.0
> NuGet-Paket-Manager in Visual Studio. Weitere Informationen zu NuGet finden Sie unter "http://docs.nuget.org/".
>
> Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015 ENU   14.0.23025
> Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015 ENU
>
> PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
> Microsoft Visual Studio-Erweiterung zur Visualisierung aggregierter Zusammenfassungen vom PreEmptive Analytics-Produkt.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.50616.0
> Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> Syntax Visualizer   1.0
> An extension for visualizing Roslyn SyntaxTrees.
>
> TortoiseGitToolbar   1.0
> Lightweight toolbar for launching commonly used TortoiseGit functionality from within Visual Studio.
>
> Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0
> Dieses Paket enthält die erforderlichen Visual Studio-Integrationskomponenten für Workflow Manager.
> ```

Comment: Works fine on my box, not sure how you got into that state.  Try running VS in safe mode.

Comment: @ChrisO +1 for trying safe mode. /SafeMode seems to have no effect. Are you using Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Affirmative, tested with VS2015.

Comment: @ChrisO I added my current installed plugins info from the about VS dialog. Can you validate with your configuration / post your configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a VS2015 bug, here's a blog post on how to log a bug, rather ["send a frown"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/05/05/the-easiest-way-to-file-bugs-and-send-error-logs-for-visual-studio-2015.aspx).  **Be warned, that by default, sending a bug report in that manner will also send a screen capture of your entire desktop** so if you have any bugs in your source, make sure they look pretty ;-)

If you have a VM around, you can try a clean install of VS2015, then apply your add-ins, one at a time, to see if any are the culprits.

Still waiting for Update 1 to get released... there's a few bugs in the debugger that will hopefully get fixed soon.

Enterprise installed with all options (I think I checked everything at install), versions are the same as yours, but with the following components list:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.00081

Installed Version: Enterprise

Architecture and Modeling Tools   00322-90000-33329-AA260
Microsoft Architecture and Modeling Tools

UML® and Unified Modeling Language™ are trademarks or registered...

Visual Basic 2015   00322-90000-33329-AA260
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-90000-33329-AA260
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   00322-90000-33329-AA260
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Visual F# 2015 RC   00322-90000-33329-AA260
Microsoft Visual F# 2015 RC

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   1.0
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools   14.0.20626.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.30624.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Color Theme Designer   1.0
Designer for creating new color themes

Common Azure Tools   1.5
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft... 

GenerateUnitTest   1.0
Generates unit test code for methods in classes under test.

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

Microsoft Code Digger   0.9
Microsoft Code Digger

Microsoft.Pex.VisualStudio   1.0
Pex

NuGet Package Manager   3.0.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet...

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from... 

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.50616.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   14.0.23121.00 D14OOB
The Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build ...
```

No clue what the `00322-90000-33329-AA260` string is, perhaps EN version of Enterprise?  But the top versions are the same as yours.  You can never have enough version strings for your app suite.